# Expectation in markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, self-learning

> A Markov Chain {$X_n,n\geq0$} with states $0,1,2$, has the transition
>   probability matrix
>   $$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{6}\\0&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{2}{3}\\\frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$$
>   If $P(X_0=0)=P(X_0=1)=\frac{1}{4}$, find $E[X_3]$.

I'm not so sure, because $X_3$ it is outside the states $$P(X_{n+1}=j|X_n=i)$$ $$E[X_3]=0P(X_3=0)+1P(X_3=1)+2P(X_3=2)$$
that's what they want to mean?

Comment: That is the correct expression for $E[X_3]$ if you include the initial distribution. Use standard techniques to compute the conditional probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct way to calculate $E[X_3]$
$$E[X_3]=0P(X_3=0)+1P(X_3=1)+2P(X_3=2)$$
The $3$ corresponds to the temporal dimension, not the spatial dimension, which can be any $n$ from $0$ onward.

You have sufficient information to calculate the probabilities of being in each spatial state at time $3$.  You are given the initial probabilities $P(X_0 = i_0)$ and the transition probabilities $P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1} | X_n = i_n)$.

Comment: Is there any way to calculate this expectation without finding $P^3$?

Comment: Not that I can think of but it's not very difficult.  The value is ultimately $w^t T^3 v$ where $T$ is your transition matrix, $w$ is the all $(0, 1, 2)$ vector, and $v$ is a vector with the $P(X_0)$ distirbution.

Comment: Interesting this, which book you used to study stochastic processes? It seems to me that the book I am using is too basic.

Comment: @JohnSheridan It's been a long time since I learned this material so I can't quite remember.  Richard Durrett's - Probability: Theory and Examples is very good.

Comment: One thing that confused me, this should not have $P(X_0=2)$?

Comment: It implicitly does.  They are just throwing another trick at you.  $P(X_0 = 0 \> \textrm{or}\>  1) = 1/2$ so that implies...